# New Beta Theme Launched

Tags: discussion

Your site looks a bit different today. Yes, we are getting rid of the 'Sketchy' look and replacing it with a more-polished and finished design for sites in beta.

You can read more about the redesign of our Beta theme on our [blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/).

Please note: This will not affect your "graduation" status in any way. When your site is due for graduation, it will get its final(real) site design and branding.

If you're still seeing the old favicon, please do a hard browser refresh. (Although sometimes it may take Chrome a while to load the new image).

If you see any CSS or styling issues, please report it **[in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126185/new-stack-exchange-beta-theme)** I created on Meta Stack Overflow. It will be easier for me to track all the bug reports there.

Comment: At first I though we finally made it out of beta. Can't tell you how disappointed I was once I noticed my mistake. :( However after reading the blog post I really welcome the change.

Comment: @musiKk Before entering Beta, there will be a discussion where you're being proposed the new Theme and the community discusses it. It's not done silently. :)